# Different Class for each item in the loop (Laravel)

Tags: php, for-loop, laravel, foreach

currently i have

```
@foreach (array_chunk($posts->all(), 3) as $row)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($row as $post)  
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1>$post->title</h1>
                <p>
                    {{ Str::limit($post->body, 50, link_to_route('posts.show', ' ...', $post->id)) }}
                </p>
            </div>  
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
@endforeach
```

which each item will now have the `col-md-4`, but what i wanna do is somthing like the below

```
@foreach (array_chunk($posts->all(), 3) as $row)
    @for ($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1>{{ $row[$i]->title }}</h1>
                <p>
                    {{ Str::limit($row[$i]->body, 50, link_to_route('posts.show', ' .....', $row[$i]->id)) }}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h1>{{ $row[$i]->title }}</h1>
                <p>
                    {{ Str::limit($row[$i]->body, 50, link_to_route('posts.show', ' .....', $row[$i]->id)) }}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <h1>{{ $row[$i]->title }}</h1>
                <p>
                    {{ Str::limit($row[$i]->body, 50, link_to_route('posts.show', ' .....', $row[$i]->id)) }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    @endfor
@endforeach
```

now each item have the class i want but unfortunately also each item will be repeated 3 times likes so

[image]

,is there away to achieve the above without being repeated.

Comment: @dfsq ,i was trying to do just that but was lost ,thanx :).

Comment: Is the class to use part of the post, or part of its position on the page? The answer will change depending on which it is.

Comment: @Erik, sorry i cant understand what exactly u mean.

Comment: You have counter that goes 0, 1, 2. Do(pseudo code) `if i=0 class=col-md-5`. And `if i=1 class=col-md-4` etc..

Comment: The classes you use, are they "the first post", "the second post", "the third post", or do they belong specifically to the post itself? If you were to move the current top post to the last position, would the css-class change? I'm guessing it wouldn't, but because of their strange numbering, I have to ask.

Comment: @Erik , the col-md-? are classes in the bootstrap FW ,and each div should represent a post in its own ,so yes its the 1st/2nd/3rd post ,then in the next loop it should be 4th/5th/6th etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you always want the row to be in 3 columns, with `md-4`, `md-3`, `md-5` column width in that order?

```
@foreach (array_chunk($posts->all(), 3) as $row)
    <div class="row">
        <?php $i = 0; ?>
        @foreach ($row as $post)  
            <?php if ($i===0) echo '<div class="col-md-4">'; ?>
            <?php if ($i===1) echo '<div class="col-md-3">'; ?>
            <?php if ($i===2) echo '<div class="col-md-5">'; ?>
                <h1>$post->title</h1>
                <p>
                    {{ Str::limit($post->body, 50,
                    link_to_route('posts.show', ' ...', $post->id))
                    }}
                </p>
            </div>  
            <php $i++;?>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: yes but the code above gives error ,after fixing it i dont have any col-md-? instead i have 3 items above each other in each row check http://cl.ly/image/0c3D400T0x1R/1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Take your current code, add a condition to the line `<div class="col-md-4">` and depending on the number of posts add different classes to the div. You need example?

Comment: an example would be very helpful yes.

Comment: @g_m was faster. Just replace `div` with his example.

Comment: Or you can use other conditions, for ex.:

Answer (score 0):

In case of more than 3 posts, and you want this specific order:

```
@foreach (array_chunk($posts->all(), 3) as $row)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($row as $post)  
            @if (i%3 == 0)
                <div class="col-md-4">
            @elseif (i%3 == 1)
                <div class="col-md-3">
            @elseif (i%3 == 2)
                <div class="col-md-5">
            @endif
                <h1>$post->title</h1>
                <p>
                    {{ Str::limit($post->body, 50, link_to_route('posts.show', '...', $post->id)) }}
                </p>
            </div>  
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: how about the other posts that are greater than those numbers ,i mean i have like 30 post and i want to loop over all of them.

Comment: Use the modulus operator.This will give you the same order over and over.

Comment: There will only ever be up to 3 items in `$row` because you have chunked the array to a max of 3.

Comment: i tried to edit the answer but the mods wouldn't allow it ,anyway the fix were for the `if > elseif` the condition should be in `""` then at last it'll always use the `col-md-4` and ignore the others.